# Process.Start on Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

```
If IsProcessRunning("record") = False Then
    Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\script\record.exe")
End If
```

Where "record" is a small script.exe inside a directory. My problem is that I get a "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'" error even though the directory is fine. Since the program will change directories I can't use the full directory that is why I am using the `CurrentDirectory` command.

Comment: How are you verifying that "the directory is fine"?

Comment: If I copy the full directory of the .exe and Process.Start it opens with no errors.

Comment: "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\solution\script\record.exe" is the directory I try to access and since everything behind solution folder will change when I transfer this to another computer.

Comment: Have you looked to see what the value Environment. Currentdirectory is ? It may not be what you expect if you are running in VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `"\script\record.exe"` in the same folder as your application you could to this:

```
Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\script\record.exe")
```

But while testing, if you run the program from within Visual Studio then `Application.StartupPath` will be something like `"C:\Program Files\Visual Studio\YourAppName\bin\debug"` or similar. You will have to take that into consideration which means that when testing then `"\script\record.exe"` should be inside that "debug" folder.

Comment: For this purpose, you might be better off getting the folder of the executing assembly.